# Load Testing Ajax application

Tags: load-testing

I have used Selenium for functional tetsing. Now I am looking for a tool for load testing. The application developed using Ajax/Rich Faces.
Application:
We use Cas Log in.
The application lists around 30 to 35 classes available for registration
The regsitartion opens up at certain time so around 200-300 users will log in and register.
There are limited seats so once it gets filled up regsitration will not go through and a message will be given.

I need to test this senario..

I tried Jmeter but actual regsitration; inserting data does not happen. The recorded test run without errors but does not make the registration. Open Source Webload does not record https..
Selenium Grid?
Any other Open souce tool?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. How would I do that? I have cookie manager. But I get Invliad ticket exception. When I record and play I see the user loged in..entry the logs despite of ticket exception. But when I closed the .jmx and open it and rerun it does not work; I do not see entry in logs. I think I need to use regular expression ..how?

Answer (score 1):

JMEter should work for you, but may not work with the basic record/playback.  The same will be true for all of the record/playback tools that I am aware of.  Any xmlhttp request (request initiated by javascript/ajax) will not be recorded and replayed.  You can use the JMeter proxy which will record all of the requests for you, or you will need to construct the request by hand (using something like fiddler or httpwatch to get the details) and replay that.  More details: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Proxy_Server

Comment: A recording proxy sitting between the browser and server ought to capture Ajax requests, but of course there is no guarantee the Ajax requests will be valid during playback.

Comment: That's true, especially if there is authentication, what will be recorded and played back by default is a session cookie, which will change with each log in, so you would need to execute the login request, extract the session cookie info and replace the session cookie in all future requests with that one, but that's a whole different question :-)